# Creative software

Tags: software-installation, photo-editing

Considering moving to elementary and as a musician and photographer, I'm wondering if it supports standard music software like cubase or reason and photography software like Adobe Photoshop?

If it doesn't does it work well under virtualized environments like virtual box or wine?

Thanks

Femo

Answer (score 0):

There are Linux alternatives to Adobe Photoshop like GIMP and Krita, but you can use Adobe Photoshop with Wine. This is a good article on that:
https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-install-adobe-photoshop-cs5-on-linux-with-wine/

For music making software for Linux, check out this article:
https://www.tecmint.com/free-music-creation-or-audio-editing-softwares-for-linux/